# Can't handle rollback-war-flag

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm admin in a Team/Channel and just saw an auto-flag about a rollback-war. As I'm not a real mod, I don't know how this *should* look, but I guess there should be more options than "No action needed", which is by the way not working as well (nothing happens, when I click the button).

[image: flag]

Comment: The only options that regular moderators have for that flag are "close question...", "no action needed...", and "delete question". Generally, our response to that is to mark the flag as helpful if it truly was a rollback war, then take manual action depending on the situation.

Comment: Okay, this is a bit screwed up, I can do it, because I am a mod on Stack Overflow as well.

Comment: @Bhargav did it handle that flag or some random flag somewhere on SO? :p

Comment: @JonClements Damn!! Didn't check that out